# MySQL dump tables from remote server

Tags: mysql, mysqldump

I'm trying to dump all tables of a specific MySQL database into each file(s) per table from a remote server.

I tried to use `mysqldump` with option `--tab=dir_name` as the output directory, but it seems only work locally. When I do it with option `--host=remote_db_ip` to connect to remote DB server, it only produces .sql files (with only table structure inside) on my server, and throws the following errors because it is using `SELECT INTO OUTFILE` which is trying to find that output path on the remote server machine.

```
mysqldump: Got error: 1: Can't create/write to file '/output/path/table_name.txt' (Errcode: 2 - No such file or directory) when executing 'SELECT INTO OUTFILE'
```

P.S. I know one workaround that is to dump to the remote DB server first then transfer back to my server, but the target database is huge and there is not enough extra disk space for storing dump output on the remote DB server.

MySQL version: 5.6

Answer (score 1):

You could temporarily set up a `sshfs` mount of the target directory and use `--tab=dir_name` on that mounted directory.

Answer (score 0):

Use `information_schema`.`TABLES` to generate one of these for each table:

```
mysqldump ... -h source_host  |  mysql ... -h target_host
```

Then copy them to execute them.

This uses a "pipe" instead of a disk file between the two commands, thereby avoiding what seems to be a permission problem.

Comment: I'm dumping them for archive purpose so no need to execute right away. Also it is the wrong machine being used instead of "permission problem". Thanks any way.